# Node Mongoose TypeError: object is not a function with Array.map and Model.create

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting some unexpected behavior out of Mongoose: when I use Model.create as an argument in a mapping function, I receive an error

```
variables.map(Variable.create);

TypeError: object is not a function
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Array.map (native)
```

but when I wrap the Model.create in an anonymous function, I don't receive the error:

```
variables.map(function(variable) {
  return Variable.create(variable);
});
```

What gives?

Using `"node": "0.10.33"` and `"mongoose": "3.8.25"`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you've stumbled into the world of Javascript objects and their methods/properties.

The short answer is internally the method `create` uses other object properties/methods from `Variable`. When you pass `Variable.create` to the mapping function it passes a reference to `create` directly and so the prototype chain is now broken. If you really want to do it that way you could use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind it back to it's parent object:

```
variables.map(Variables.create.bind(Variables));
```

```js
var objA = {
  word: 'bar',
  say: function() {
    alert(this.word);
  }
};

var objB = {
  word: 'foo',
  say: function() {
    alert(this.word);
  }
};

var say = objA.say;
var bound = objA.say.bind(objB);

objA.word; // bar
objA.say(); // bar

objB.word; // foo
objB.say(); // foo

say(); // undefined --> this.word
bound(); // foo

// bonus fun
word = 'hello'; // 'this' is the global scope here so this.word === word
say(); // hello
```

For the long answer I would recommend reading [**You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md).